# Hot Keys Not Working in VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player

In VLC while playing music or some videos, I the jump forward hotkeys are not working.  Jump back work fine but even if I change the jump forward keys in the settings it will not work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried wiping the settings? Option is available at install or deinstall. I'm not on a machine with VLC right now to check whether it can be done from the prefs whilst running.

Comment: OK, so I just upgraded and wiped the settings.  The forward keys are still not working.

Comment: None of the 3 jump forward options work? By default they are Ctrl/right arrow, alt/right arrow & shift/right arrow... That would make me think something may be wrong with your right arrow on the keyboard. What happens if you use something other than that?

Comment: You have to restart VLC to global hotkeys changes take effect. (By default, only local hotkeys are set = if VLC window is not active, shortcuts don't work. For setting global hotkeys, doubleclick to corresponding column in hotkey settings)

Answer (score 7):

I discovered (at least on Mac) that you have to save, completely quit VLC (Cmd+Q may work - i.e. make sure all instances are closed) and then restart VLC and open your video.
The keyboard shortcuts should work now, at least it did in my case.

Comment: Looks like nobody else reviewed your contribution.  You can ignore the comment that was automatically generated.  In order to cleanup the comment section I deleted my previous comment.  The comment generated automatically will remain.

Comment: Holy crap that was it!!  This has been driving me nuts for ages.  Thank you!!!!

Comment: This answer worked for me with VLC 2.2.2 on a Linux debian based.

Comment: Can't believe it was as simple as a restart of VLC, thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! This was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this problem after upgrading to Windows 10.  I often have to write in **Spanish**, so I have several different keyboard profiles.

With Windows 10 (*and possibly other versions of Windows after Windows 7*), the change of the keyboard layout is global (*in Windows 7 and earlier, the keyboard layout was tied to the individual applications that you were running*).

I discovered that with the **U.S. International keyboard layout**, the value of the Right <kbd>ALT</kbd> key is different (it maps to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>, at least in VLC).

Anyway, for me this was causing "jumping" problems in VLC; once I changed back to the normal U.S. keyboard layout, everything worked as expected.

So having the wrong keyboard layout selected is at least one possible reason for odd, unexplained keyboard behaviour.

Comment: This was my problem for Windows 10. I was on the Japanese keyboard. It seems VLC doesn't use the actual keyboard key for the hotkey but the converted to Microsoft IME keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Use shift + arrow key to jump forward/backward in 3 seconds.
Use ctrl + arrow key to jump forward/backward in 1 min.

Answer (score 0):

Found in another site:
The problem is that by default the left and right arrow keys are assigned to DVD options ("navigate left" and "navigate right"). This overrides the use of those keys for jumping through a video. The solution is simple! Just unassign those hotkeys (or assign them to other keys). Hey Presto, the problem is fixed.

Comment: I'm trying to use the left and right arrow keys in conjunction with shift, control, and option (on a Mac) to jump forward and backwards various amounts, but even after assigning, they *still* do nothing!   Are the arrows somehow special, ignoring my assignments?

Answer (score -1):

Hello there are no jumper
for keyboard for the functions,
maybe should help a autohotkey-jumper,
to open the menu with alt+l and
than step by step with the scene-record
name of window in action.
an e.G. program like this,
at 
https://gigaom.com/2008/07/01/automate-routine-firefox-tasks-with-dejaclick/
records events in firefox but not the menu-events.
Andrew